# https request from Nao in python dont work

Tags: python, https, nao-robot

From some months ago, https request from Nao (on Choreographe) doesnt work on python.

I search on google because the problem is with ssl version (1.0.0), but I cant update the python version and i cant install pip

are there some solution for use https requests on Nao??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the python packages that are involved with the ssl connection.
That helped me on Pepper.
List your packages with

```
python -m pip list
```

then upgrade pip as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387823/install-things-on-pepper) and try to update the packages six, urllib3 and requests.

```
 pip install --user urllib3 -U
```

That might help.

But better remember what versions where installed to be able to revert to the previous configuration.