# Am not able to install SpeechRecognition module on Pepper

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

Hello I am trying to install speechrecogntion python module on Pepper by using the below command.
pip install SpeechRecognition

I am getting the below error.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SpeechRecognition-3.8.1.dist-info'

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387823/install-things-on-pepper): You don't have root access on Pepper, which limits where you can install.

your command tries to install the package to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` where you would need root acceess to write.

If you updated pip try:

```
/home/nao/.local/bin/pip install --user SpeechRecognition
```

if not try:

```
pip install --user SpeechRecognition
```

this will install the package to another directory where you have write access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right , just to add you don’t need to use path as only pip install - - user packagename will work. Thank you very much

Comment: If you only use "pip install ..." you will use the default pip of version 1.4.1.
But it is recommended to update pip as decribed in the link above.
If you use "/home/nao/.local/bin/pip install ..." you will instead use the updated version of pip.