# how to install python packages into nao's gentoo?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, installation, nao-robot

I want to install numpy,PIL packages into Nao robot's hardware for my project. (python 2.7, Nao 1.14.5 Gentoo lınux) How Could I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387823/install-things-on-pepper): You might also not have root access on Nao, which limits where you can install.

you can install python packages with pip install but you need the --user tag

upgrade pip as descriped in the other post and

try

```
pip install --user yourPackage
```

respective:

```
/home/nao/.local/bin/pip install --user yourPackage
```

this will install the package to a directory where you have write access without root.

Comment: How can I acces Nao's hardware to install packages? from pc or whatelse?

Comment: Well, you could connect via ssh with a programm called putty.
How depends on your OS.
Please read the documentation here: 
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/tools/opennao.html#accessing-nao-over-ssh