# Create Python wrapper with libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, pepper

I'm trying to use a Pepper robot for face mask detection. My problem is that the program I'm using is based on Tensorflow, but I can't install it on the robot. I realised that this is really hard to install new packages on the robot, as `pip` is not  up-to-date (and it's impossible to update it, even manually) and there's no packages manager.

So I wonder if it's possible to make something like a Python wrapper, which could contain all the necessary libraries, without needing to install them on the robot's OS (the OS is based on Gentoo).

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387823/install-things-on-pepper

Answer (score 0):

If `pip` cannot be upgraded, you can always install `conda` as a package manager which is found within the [Anaconda python distribution](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).

Then you can simply install any python package, like:

```sh
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

To install it on Gentoo, check out the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/).